# How to sorting listview item after add new item

Tags: android, sorting, listview, android-fragments

I am a newbie in android. I tried working with custom listview and have some problem.  I have 2 fragments, Fragment A show listview, Fragment B to Add new item. When I click button add in Fragment B, Fragment A will display and I want new items will add in listview then sorting listview follow Alphabel. Every things look great, but when item is added in ListView, it's always located at the end listview and didn't sorting with old items. My ListView just sorting items that i just add into listview. For examlple: my listview display name: Ironman, Captain, Warmachine. I add new name are: Dare Devil, Alibaba, Songoku. The listView will show as: Captain, Ironman, Warmachine, Alibaba, Dare Devil, Songoku. I want my listview must so: Alibaba, Captain, DareDevel, Ironman, Songoku and warachine. Anyone can let me know how can I do that ?.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IMainClass, ICommunicator{
private  ArrayList<StudentModel> arrayListStudent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    displayFragment();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void findViewByID() {

}

@Override
public void displayFragment() {
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body,mainFragment, "main");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void eventClickButton() {

}


@Override
public void add(StudentModel studentModel) {
    MainFragment mainFragment = (MainFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main");
    mainFragment.addStudentToList(studentModel);
}
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class ArrayAdapterStudent extends ArrayAdapter<StudentModel> {
List<StudentModel> listStudent;
@Override
public int getPosition(StudentModel item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

public ArrayAdapterStudent(Context context, int resource, List<StudentModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.listStudent = objects;
}

@Override
public StudentModel getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public Context getContext() {
    return super.getContext();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_listview,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        viewHolder.tvAge = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_age);
        viewHolder.tvClass = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_class);
        viewHolder.tvSubject = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subjects);
        viewHolder.chkStudent = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_student);
        viewHolder.chkStudent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                listStudent.get(getPosition).set_isChecked(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.tvName.setText("Name: "+listStudent.get(position).get_name());
    viewHolder.tvAge.setText("Age: "+listStudent.get(position).get_age()+"");
    viewHolder.tvClass.setText("Class: "+listStudent.get(position).get_class());
    viewHolder.tvSubject.setText("Subject: "+listStudent.get(position).get_subject());
    viewHolder.chkStudent.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.chkStudent.setChecked(listStudent.get(position).is_Checked());
    return convertView;
}
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public class ViewHolder {
TextView tvName, tvAge,tvClass,tvSubject;
CheckBox chkStudent;
```

}

**ListFragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements IMainClass {
private ListView lvStudent;
private Button btnAdd;
ArrayAdapterStudent arrayAdapterStudent;
private  ArrayList<StudentModel> arrayListStudent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listStudent();
    Log.d("Test"," OnCreate");
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    findViewByID();
    loadStudentToListView();
    choosingStudentInListView();
    deleteStudent();
    eventClickButton();
    Log.d("Test", " OnActivityCreate");

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


private void loadStudentToListView(){
    /*Collections.sort(arrayListStudent, new Comparator<StudentModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(StudentModel lhs, StudentModel rhs) {
            return  lhs.get_name().compareTo(rhs.get_name());
        }
    });
    */
    arrayAdapterStudent = new ArrayAdapterStudent(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_row_listview,arrayListStudent);
    arrayAdapterStudent.sort(new Comparator<StudentModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(StudentModel lhs, StudentModel rhs) {
            return lhs.get_name().compareTo(rhs.get_name());
        }
    });

    lvStudent.setAdapter(arrayAdapterStudent);
    arrayAdapterStudent.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void findViewByID() {
    lvStudent = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_student);
    btnAdd = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
}

@Override
public void displayFragment() {

}

@Override
public void eventClickButton() {
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddNewStudentFragment addNewStudentFragment = new AddNewStudentFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, addNewStudentFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}

private void choosingStudentInListView(){
    lvStudent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            StudentModel studentModel = arrayListStudent.get(position);
            studentBundel(studentModel);
            Log.d("Test", "Student " + studentModel.is_Checked() + "is click");
        }
    });
}

private void deleteStudent(){
    lvStudent.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Notification").setMessage("Are your sure deleting this student ?")
                    .setNeutralButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            arrayListStudent.remove(position);
                            arrayAdapterStudent.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }).setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}


private void studentBundel(StudentModel studentModel){
    DetailStudentFragment detailStudentFragment = new DetailStudentFragment();
    Bundle inforStudentBundel = new Bundle();
    inforStudentBundel.putSerializable("student",studentModel);
    detailStudentFragment.setArguments(inforStudentBundel);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body,detailStudentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public ArrayList<StudentModel> listStudent(){
    String name = "";
    int age = 18;
    String Subject[] = {"Android","IOS","Java",".NET","C#"};
    int subjectPosition = 0;
    arrayListStudent = new ArrayList<StudentModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //Add student name Angela =>group name A
        name = "Angela "+i;
        StudentModel studentA = new StudentModel(name,age,"TVO",Subject[subjectPosition].toString());
        subjectPosition = subjectPosition++;
        arrayListStudent.add(studentA);

        //Add student name Beta =>Group name B
        name = "BeTa"+i;
        StudentModel studentB = new StudentModel(name,age,"TVO",Subject[subjectPosition].toString());
        subjectPosition = subjectPosition++;
        arrayListStudent.add(studentB);

        //Add student name Cadic =>Group name B
        name = "Cadic"+i;
        StudentModel studentC = new StudentModel(name,age,"TVO",Subject[subjectPosition].toString());
        subjectPosition = subjectPosition++;
        arrayListStudent.add(studentC);

        //Add Student name David
        name = "David"+i;
        StudentModel studentD = new StudentModel(name,age,"TVO",Subject[subjectPosition].toString());
        subjectPosition = subjectPosition++;
        arrayListStudent.add(studentD);

        //Add Student name Electro
        name = "Electro"+i;
        StudentModel studentE = new StudentModel(name,age,"TVO",Subject[subjectPosition].toString());
        subjectPosition = subjectPosition++;
        arrayListStudent.add(studentE);

        //Add Student name Kame
        name = "Kame"+i;
        StudentModel studentK = new StudentModel(name,age,"TVO",Subject[subjectPosition].toString());
        subjectPosition = subjectPosition++;
        arrayListStudent.add(studentK);

        //add Student name Songoku
        name = "Songoku"+i;
        StudentModel studentS = new StudentModel(name,age,"TVO",Subject[subjectPosition].toString());
        subjectPosition = subjectPosition++;
        arrayListStudent.add(studentS);
    }
    return arrayListStudent;
}

public void addStudentToList(StudentModel studentModel){
    arrayListStudent.add(studentModel);
  //  arrayAdapterStudent.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(" Test", arrayListStudent+"aaaaa");
    //
    // What is different when use arrListStudent.add an
    //arrayAdapterStudent.insert(studentModel,0);
}
```

**Add Fragment**

```
public class AddNewStudentFragment extends Fragment implements IMainClass {
private EditText edtName, edtAge, edtClass, edtSubject;
private Button btnAddNewStudent;
ICommunicator iCommunicator;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_student_fragment,container,false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    findViewByID();
    iCommunicator = (ICommunicator)getActivity();
    eventClickButton();
}

@Override
public void findViewByID() {
    edtName = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
    edtAge = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edt_age);
    edtClass = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edt_class);
    edtSubject = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edt_subject);
    btnAddNewStudent = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_add_new_student);
}

@Override
public void displayFragment() {

}

@Override
public void eventClickButton() {
    btnAddNewStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = edtName.getText().toString();
            int age = Integer.parseInt(edtAge.getText().toString());
            String classes = edtClass.getText().toString();
            String subject = edtSubject.getText().toString();
            StudentModel studentModel = new StudentModel(name, age, classes, subject);
            iCommunicator.add(studentModel);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
    });
}
```

**ICommunicator interface**

```
public interface ICommunicator {
public void add(StudentModel studentModel);
```

}

**IMain interface**

```
public interface IMainClass  {
public void findViewByID();
public void displayFragment();
public void eventClickButton();
```

}

**StudentModel**

```
public void set_name(String _name) {
    this._name = _name;
}

public int get_age() {
    return _age;
}

public void set_age(int _age) {
    this._age = _age;
}

public String get_class() {
    return _class;
}

public void set_class(String _class) {
    this._class = _class;
}

public String get_subject() {
    return _subject;
}

public void set_subject(String _subject) {
    this._subject = _subject;
}
```

}

p/s: thanks you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call notifyDataSetChanged() on the ArrayAdapter to refresh listview items.

Comment: is your mean override notifyDataSetChanged() in arrayAdapter ?

Comment: If your getPosition() override returns the right item position, notifyDataSetChanged will recreate all list items with the updated position. You don't need to override notifyDatasetChanged(), just fix getPosition() to return your ordered list item position.

Comment: it's not exactly in this case bro. I just update my answered for my problem. Thanks you for you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Call `loadStudentToListView()` after adding the new student to sort and refresh the view:

```
public void addStudentToList(StudentModel studentModel){
    arrayListStudent.add(studentModel);
    loadStudentToListView();
}
```

Comment: Try to print out a log after arrayAdapterStudent.sort(....) to check sort is working well.

Comment: It working well bro, list student i add by hard code are sorting. But when i tried add new, it just sort items that i just add :(. Don't know why :(

Comment: Sure! But Just in case, If I was in your shoes I put a log inside the sort method to check what is going on inside, like this: public int compare(StudentModel lhs, StudentModel rhs) {
 Log.i("TEST-SORT","lhs.get_name():"+lhs.get_name());
 Log.i("TEST-SORT","rhs.get_name():"+rhs.get_name());
    return lhs.get_name().compareTo(rhs.get_name());
}

Comment: thanks you bro. My problem are exactly what u say. It's can sort because the function sort have some mistake. This function sorting by ASCI format. So have different between upercase and lowecase. Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have known what is my problem. My problem come from Sorting function. This function works follow ASCII standard code, so it has difference between upercase and lowercase. So if i want my listview is sorted after insert new items. I need convert all of them upercase or lowercase. In my case, this code will be sorting exactly.

```
Collections.sort(arrayListStudent, new Comparator<StudentModel>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(StudentModel lhs, StudentModel rhs) {
       return  lhs.get_name().toUpperCase().compareTo(rhs.get_name().toUpperCase());
}
```